# Does AWS charge for shutting down S3 when I terminate an account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So we need to terminate an AWS account for a customer. This account has some rather heavy S3 buckets with tens of thousands of images. The storage class for most of these buckets are Deep Glacier.

I am unsure if there would be any hidden costs if I just terminate the account. Or do I need to delete these buckets manually? I read that the delete operator does not incur cost, but for deleting AWS needs to "list" the bucket items and that can incur cost.

What is the most cost effective way to terminate an AWS account that has heavy duty S3 buckets?

Any insight for AWS Gurus are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the relevant AWS documentation:

> Closing your account might not automatically terminate all your active resources. ***You might continue to incur charges for some of your active resources even after you close your account.*** You're charged for any usage fees incurred before closure.

REFERENCE: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/terminate-resources-account-closure/